# Vectorizing blocks of bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, bilinear-form

Math genius here. I have this problem of vectorizing the block matrix of bilinear entries as follows:
$$W=\begin{bmatrix}
e_1M_{11}e_1^T &  e_1M_{12}e_2^T\\e_2M_{21}e_1^T&e_2M_{22}e_2^T \end{bmatrix}$$

Is it possible to write the matrix $W$ as the product of some matrics whose entries are $e_1,e_2, M_{11}$ and so on.? Note that $e_1,e_2$ are vectors and $M_{ij}$ are matrics of compatible shapes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: you can write it as

$$ \begin{bmatrix} e_{1} & 0 \\ 0 & e_{2} \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} M_{11} & M_{12}\\ M_{21} & M_{22} \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} e_{1}^{T} & 0\\ 0 & e_{2}^{T} \end{bmatrix} $$
(where the zeros are blocks or the appropriate size).

Comment: That is awesome. Thanks.